# Reference regarding prepositional phrases and collocations

Tags: grammar, prepositions, prepositional-phrases, collocations

Does anyone know any good reference (books,lecture notes or webpages, preferably books or lecture notes) to study prepositional phrases and collocations? By "good" I mean a reference with clear explanations and a lot of exercises. Of course, I googled both "prepositional phrases" and "collocations" but I find several webpages with very few exercises and pretty ambiguous explanations; none of them satisfy me.

In advance thank you very much.